# Añadir listas sobre una lista - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo dos dudas en particular:

- ¿Cómo logro añadir un número indeterminado de listas en otra lista? Específicamente, deseo añadir a una lista, varias listas con 5 elementos en sus interiores (*RUT*, nombre, primera nota, segunda nota y tercera nota).
- ¿Por qué al ejecutar las lineas de código que diseñé, las listas, se repiten y **no cortan** en 5 elementos?

Programa:

```
lista=[]
lista2=[]
respuesta=""
while respuesta.lower()!="no":
    rut=lista.append(raw_input("ingrese rut del alumno: "))
    nombre=lista.append(raw_input("ingrese nombre completo del alumno: "))
    nota1=lista.append(input("ingrese la primera nota del alumno: "))
    nota2=lista.append(input("ingrese la segunda nota del alumno: "))
    nota3=lista.append(input("ingrese la tercera nota del alumno: "))
    lista2.append(lista)
    respuesta=raw_input(
      "si desea ingresar datos de otro alumno ingrese 'Si', de lo contrario, ingrese 'No' "
    )
print lista2
```

Salida de la consola de *Python*:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

ingrese rut del alumno: 17565911-k
ingrese nombre completo del alumno: juan perez
ingrese la primera nota del alumno: 44
ingrese la segunda nota del alumno: 55
ingrese la tercera nota del alumno: 66
si desea ingresar datos de otro alumno ingrese 'Si', de lo contrario, ingrese 'No' si
ingrese rut del alumno: 19565000-k
ingrese nombre completo del alumno: pedro perez
ingrese la primera nota del alumno: 70
ingrese la segunda nota del alumno: 50
ingrese la tercera nota del alumno: 34
si desea ingresar datos de otro alumno ingrese 'Si', de lo contrario, ingrese 'No' no
[
    ['17565911-k', 'juan perez', 44, 55, 66, 'pedro perez', 70, 50, 34],
    ['17565911-k', 'juan perez', 44, 55, 66, 'pedro perez', 70, 50, 34]
]
```

Comment: por favor, copia y pega el codigo en lugar de poner la imagen

Comment: oh disculpa, es que al ser nuevo, no tenia idea como escribir el codigo. Lo arreglaré de inmediato

Comment: No te preocupes, todos fuimos nuevos alguna vez, lo que pasa es que asi es mas facil que la gente pueda ayudarte, por si requiere copiar y pegar tu codigo, o en algunas ocasiones las personas tienen bloquedas las imagenes en sus puntos de acceso

Comment: estaba intentando editar el mensaje, pero no sé cómo redactar las lineas de codigo en el mensaje sin que este se desordene :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en cada iteración estás utilizando la misma lista para almacenar los datos. Debes declarar una nueva lista en cada iteración.

Al añadir un usuario, insertas los datos en `lista`, y luego insertas `lista` en `lista2`. En la siguiente iteración, añades los datos de otro usuario en la misma lista, y vuelves a insertar la misma lista en `lista2`. Como en `lista2` se almacena una referencia a `lista`, no una copia, si modificas la lista añadiendo, modificando o eliminando elementos, afectará a las listas anteriores de `lista2`. Es decir, si añades por ejemplo tres usuarios, en `lista2` realmente tienes tres referencias a la misma lista, con 15 elementos.

Simplemente debes mover la declaración de `lista` dentro del bucle:

```
lista2 = []
respuesta = ""
while respuesta.lower() != "no":
    lista = []
    rut = lista.append(raw_input("ingrese rut del alumno: "))
    nombre = lista.append(raw_input("ingrese nombre completo del alumno: "))
    nota1 = lista.append(input("ingrese la primera nota del alumno: "))
    nota2 = lista.append(input("ingrese la segunda nota del alumno: "))
    nota3 = lista.append(input("ingrese la tercera nota del alumno: "))
    lista2.append(lista)
    respuesta = raw_input("si desea ingresar datos de otro alumno ingrese 'Si', de lo contrario, ingrese 'No' ")
print lista2
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por darte el tiempo de responderme con lujo y detalle, me has aclarado todas mis dudas :D . Por cierto, aprovechando tu respuesta, quisiera preguntarte: si deseo seguir trabajando con esta lista de listas, ya sea obteniendo el promedio de notas de cada usuario, el mejor promedio de todos los usuarios o verificar si cada usuario aprobó o reprobó,  ¿ debo trabajar dentro del bucle o fuera del bucle ? Saludos y muchas gracias nuevamente

Comment: En el mismo bucle podrías calcular la media de cada usuario y almacenarla en la lista, y llevar una variable auxiliar para almacenar la mejor media hasta el momento. Pero depende de cómo lo quieras enfocar. Podrías crear una nueva clase `Alumno` donde almacenar el nombre y las notas, y crear métodos para calcular la media o comprobar si está aprobado o no (y en el bucle almacenar alumnos en la lista, en lugar de listas).

Comment: volviendo al primer problema, arregle el programa tal como me sugeriste e  ingrese los datos de 2 usuarios y al imprimir, no se imprimen 2 listas con 5 elementos cada una dentro de una lista, sino mas bien, se imprime 1 lista con 10 elementos, dentro de una lista :(  . Sin embargo, pude solucionar la segunda duda que tenia mi pregunta

Comment: Acabo de ejecutar el código y funciona correctamente. Después del bucle, haz otro bucle para imprimir cada elemento de `lista2` y comprobarlo: `for x in lista2: print x`. O mira la longitud de la lista: `print len(lista2)`.

Comment: sip, acabo de revisar y tienes toda la razon, yo me equivoque al ingresar la lista equivocada dentro del bucle.  Estabas en lo correcto, disculpa haberte hecho perder el tiempo, tu codigo estaba perfecto :, yo fui el que me equivoque :(  . Muchas gracias, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente ingresa lista dentro del while para que se inicie nuevamente.

```
lista2=[]
respuesta=""
while respuesta.lower()!="no":
    lista=list()
    rut=lista.append(raw_input("ingrese rut del alumno: "))
    nombre=lista.append(raw_input("ingrese nombre completo del alumno: "))
    nota1=lista.append(input("ingrese la primera nota del alumno: "))
    nota2=lista.append(input("ingrese la segunda nota del alumno: "))
    nota3=lista.append(input("ingrese la tercera nota del alumno: "))
    lista2.append(lista)
    respuesta=raw_input(
      "si desea ingresar datos de otro alumno ingrese 'Si', de lo contrario, ingrese 'No' "
    )
print lista2
```

Comment: muchas gracias, por cierto utilizar list() es lo mismo que declarar una lista vacía ?